# Lists with various data types inside ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm new to ocaml so I am wondering why this doesn't work.

```
let lst : (string * int * char) list = ["1"; 2; '3'];;
```

And how would I be able to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This is a list of tuples that are shaped like `(string * int * char)`.

Most likely what you're looking for is a variant type. https://dev.realworldocaml.org/variants.html

```ml
type mix = | Str of string | Int of int | Char of char

let lst : mix list = [Str "1"; Int 2; Char '3']
```